# How to avoid precompiled headers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to compile a simple VS program in C++ as an assignment for class. We only ever include `<iostream>` and I keep getting this error:

> 1>Assignment.cpp(15): fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add `'#include "StdAfx.h"'` to your source?

My program is literally this small...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned int day = 30;

    cout << "My Name is John Doe" << endl;
    cout << "My Major is CS" << endl;
    cout << "I was born on day " << day << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I just installed Visual Studio Express 2010. Really I would love to start an empty project instead of installing with all these files predefined, I think it would make it a lot easier but I never get that option when creating a project. Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: You need to turn off the use of precompiled headers in your project's settings (you can also uncheck Use Precompiled Headers when creating new projects in the future.)

Comment: How do I go about turning this off for future projects?

Comment: Please improve your question title. It does not describe the question very will, but instead lists technologies (which is what tags are for).

Comment: I got Project Properties, but I do not see precompiled Headers. It is in langauge properties?

Comment: Look under C/C++ -> Precompiled Headers.

Comment: BTW you're missing some indentation in your `int main()`, and `return 0;` is optional in `main`.

Comment: @ildjarn: I was hoping that the OP could indent his code himself, as a learning exercise. Thanks though.

Comment: @Tomalak : Editing poor indentation is a matter of habit now, so I didn't see your comment until after the fact. :-P

Comment: @ildjarn: Heh; by no means are you alone.

Comment: So how do you turn precompiled headers for future projects? I disabled them for my project: https://i.imgur.com/sqlFuBF.png . But there is no checkbox Use Precompiled Headers when creating new projects in the future.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can always disable the use of pre-compiled headers in the project settings.

Instructions for VS 2010 (should be similar for other versions of VS):

> Select your project, use the "Project -> Properties" menu and go to the "Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Precompiled Headers" section, then change the "Precompiled Header" setting to "Not Using Precompiled Headers" option.

---

If you are only trying to setup a minimal Visual Studio project for simple C++ command-line programs (such as those developed in introductory C++ programming classes), you can create an [empty C++ project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9x39eaw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: See, I tried this but then I do not get the "Press Enter To Continue" By default when I print out strings. It is fairly annoying.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee `std::cout << "Press Enter To Continue" << std::endl; std::cin.get();` should get you there.

Comment: Is there a way I can get that to happen by default? In class we never need to add any of that extra code to get the press enter to continue string.

Comment: You can press CTRL+F5, but it won't allow you to debug code. It's called "Start Without Debugging".

Comment: See that's is exactly what I thought, but doing this in an empty project still exits out of cmd prompt before I can actually see the strings I've printed. Doing the ctrl + f5 that is - even in debug mode it does not give me the "press enter to continue" option

Comment: @Howdy: The proper way to handle that is to execute your program in a persistent console window. It is not the job of your program to compensate for your having used a temporary console window, by arbitrarily waiting for user input that it never uses.

Comment: Setting Linker -> System to Console should display the message again.

Comment: @Tom K: note that `std::cin.get()` is not required to block on console input.  I know that at least on GCC, it returns `-1` if no input is available.

Comment: -1 What do precompiled headers have to do with standards compliance?

Comment: @ildjarn: Nothing.  However, all other C++ project types in Visual Studio require some non-standard entry point (`wMain`, `WinMain`, ...).  The empty C++ project is the only one that will compile a small, self-contained, standard C++ command-line program such as the one posted by OP.

Comment: @André : The 'Win32 Project' and 'Win32 Console Application' templates also give the option of disabling precompiled headers. In any case, my point was that since his issue is related to precompiled headers, and precompiled headers are orthogonal with standards compliance, it's misleading to bring up standards compliance at all.

Comment: @ildjarn: but the issue is not about pre-compiled headers.  The real issue is about OP having selected the wrong project type and/or options in the project wizard dialog.  Since OP is writing school assignments in what seems to be plain, standard C++, the project type that best helps develop good habits for writing standard compliant C++ programs in Visual Studio is the empty project type.  Hence, my mention of standards compliance.

Comment: @André: `traits::eof()` really, not `-1`.

Comment: @ildjarn: re-worded to remove mention of "standards compliance".

Comment: You say that I can disable the precompiled header, but somewhat you don't care to say how. -1

Comment: @TomášZato: Added instructions for VS2010.  Next time, you can simply ask instead of downvoting...

Comment: Downovote's tooltip says: "*This answer is not useful*". That's, of course, relative. As well, downvote can be reverted any time. Thank you for improving the answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can create an empty project by selecting the "Empty Project" from the "General" group of Visual C++ projects (maybe that project template isn't included in Express?).

To fix the problem in the project you already have, open the project properties and navigate to:

```
Configuration Properties | C/C++ | Precompiled Headers
```

And choose "Not using Precompiled Headers" for the "Precompiled Header" option.

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235516%28v=VS.100%29.aspx, the Empty Project template is in Express.  Let me know if it doesn't show up for you.  I find it preferable to any of the other project templates for setting up a quick-n-dirty, small, self-contained test project.

Answer (score 6):

The `.cpp` file is configured to use precompiled header, therefore it must be included first (before iostream). For Visual Studio, it's name is usually "stdafx.h".

If there are no stdafx* files in your project, you need to go to this file's options and set it as “Not using precompiled headers”.

Comment: How do I go about turning the predefined headers off?

Comment: Right click on the .cpp file and choose Properties, then locate C/C++ / Precompiled Headers in the treeview and change the Precompiled Header option.

Comment: Also handy is the mass select <CTRL> + Left Mouse option. Select a bunch of _cpp_ source files in the Solution Explorer and turn off as above.

Answer (score 0):

try to add `#include "stdafx.h"` before `#include "iostream"`

Comment: It's a class assignment - I'm only allowed to use iostream so this solution will not work

Comment: @Howdy: Well technically Sergey is correct; you have created a project set to use a precompiled header, yet you don't `#include` it.  What you really need to do is create an empty project or remove the reliance on pre-compiled headers.

Comment: @Ed S.: although it is correct, it only fixes the symptom.  The hidden question is "why can't I compile the same program I compiled in class"?  And the answer to *that* question is "in class, the project didn't use a pre-compiled header".