# Visual Studio: Compiler now looking for pre-compiled headers after building ok for a week. I only have .c files

Tags: c, visual-studio

Compiler output.

Error   1   error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?   C:\Users\Cathal\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Go\Go\go.c    367 1   Go

Was working fine then all of a sudden the compiler starts asking for the precompiled headers which I turned off in the project properties.

**ANSWER**

I figured out that one of the projects (two projects in solution) had different configuration settings that was screwing the solution up. Can't mix and match of course. I wish VS would highlight this.

Comment: Might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261707/how-to-avoid-precompiled-headers

Comment: Don't put the answer into your question. You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

look up for all projects in the solution and check this 
[image]