# Visual Studio 2017 community settings/options not taking effect

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have spent the last 2 days trying to setup the linker for a c++ SMFL project. Following this setup https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-vc.php this was not working, the issue seemed like the linker settings were not taking effect in the project I could not call the files inside the include even though the files were correctly linked. I tried starting over with a new project and removing the per-compiled header files aka stdafx.

I kept getting this error

[image: pre-compiled error]

So I re-ran VS as admin, Updated to the newest version of VS2017

[image: proof of update].

The update changed stdafx to pch  I still try to disable it and get the same error as before is this an issue with VS2017 Community? here are my project settings

[image: Settings for Project]

project code

[image: Project]

error message

[image: Error]

here is the code

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    cont << "hello world\n";
}
```

Comment: [Turn off precompiled headers altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261707/how-to-avoid-precompiled-headers)

Comment: Solved the issue, I had to make sure that the platform for the settings was the same as the build and release platform.

Comment: Hi, for future question, anything that is text should be posted as text, no images of text please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue, I had to make sure that the platform for the settings was the same as the build and release platform.

[image]