# How to disable precompiled headers with msbuild?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, precompiled-headers

**The problem**

- I have a VS2015 solution that uses precompiled headers.
- Our Continuous Integration server builds the solution using `msbuild`.
- We also use a coverage tool that has some issues with precompiled headers.

**The question**

How to tell to `msbuild.exe` do not use precompiled headers?

**Note**

I tried adding `/Y-` in the `msbuild` call, but it's not a valid parameter for `msbuild`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We can't directly do this by msbuild since `PrecompiledHeader` is not a msbuild property...

MSbuild reads data from project file to execute the build. And there're several elements in `xx.vcxproj` can be specified in command-line like [targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2019), [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019#global-properties), so we can use command like msbuild xx.vcxproj/xx.sln /t:xx /p:xx to specify the `target` element and `property` element when building in command-line.

**e.g**: `msbuild xx.vcxproj /t:build /p:OutDir=xxx` can specify where to output your assembly.

I changed one VS2015 [C++ project's settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7261771/10910450) to make it not use `precompiled headers`, after comparing the difference(using git for version control) between the two versions of the xx.vcxproj file I found:

[image]

So the element to control the behavior of precompiled-header is an [Item metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2019#item-metadata) in `ClCompile` [Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2019). Since the element is an `Item metadata` instead of a `property`, we **can't** use command like `msbuild xx.vcxproj /p:PrecompiledHeader=NotUsing ...` to disable the precompiled headers. (`/p` <=> `/property`)

**Possible direction:**

The only possible direction I can imagine which may work to achieve your goals is creating a custom property to control this behavior.

1.For a normal C++ project, the content of its project file is:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>NotUsing</PrecompiledHeader>
      ...
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>

  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      ...
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>

  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      ...
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>

  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      ...
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

2.Add a custom `DisablePCH` property, make a `copy` of these four `ItemDefinitionGroups` and involve this property into their [Condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2019).

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DisablePCH>false</DisablePCH>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32' And '$(DisablePCH)'=='false'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      ...
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>

  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64' And '$(DisablePCH)'=='false'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      ...
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>

  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32' And '$(DisablePCH)'=='false'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      ...
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>

  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64' And '$(DisablePCH)'=='false'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      ...
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>

<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32' And '$(DisablePCH)'=='true'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>NotUsing</PrecompiledHeader>
      ...
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>

  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64' And '$(DisablePCH)'=='true'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>NotUsing</PrecompiledHeader>
      ...
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>

  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32' And '$(DisablePCH)'=='true'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>NotUsing</PrecompiledHeader>
      ...
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>

  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64' And '$(DisablePCH)'=='true'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>NotUsing</PrecompiledHeader>
      ...
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

3.Then by default if we use normal command like `msbuild xx.vcxproj ...` , it will use the precompiledheaders. If we want to disable it in command, use command like `msbuild xx.vcxproj /p:DisablePCH=true ...`.

ps:If you do want to disable PCH(precompiled headers) by msbuild, you can try the `possible direction`, for some reason I'm not able to test it in my machine :(. Feel free to let me know if it helps or not.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer, it helped me a lot. Finally, I end up resolving my problem by disabling precompiled headers from my coverage tool (using a pretty hidden argument), but this answer clarify many doubts using msbuild.